# DM in Berlin open during christmas?

Tags: berlin, public-holidays

Unfortunately, I could not find anything by myself, I desperately need [DM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-drogerie_markt) at 25 December in Berlin (any place), so is there any chance I find it?

http://www.in-berlin-brandenburg.com/Einkaufen_Berlin/Verkaufsoffener-Sonntag/Sonntags-in-Berlin-geoeffnet.html

[Here's the list](http://www.einkaufsbahnhof.de/berlin-suedkreuz/dm-s5922) of markets open on Sundays and found DM at Berlin Südkreuz, but it says nothing about Christmas.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The thing is that the 25th of December is a public holiday - any market open on that day is likely to be open on Sundays as well. So going to a market that is regularly open on a Sunday is probably your best bet. I wouldn't expect their *actual* opening times on public holidays to be listed anywhere on the web, though. The official DM homepage has a search machine for shops and phone numbers for them - perhaps you may want to consider calling the markets before going there?

Comment: I'd say your chances are less than 1%. 25 of Dec is a big holiday in Germany, and not much is open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DM was open at **Berlin Südkreuz** , 25th December Opening hours was : 13:00 - 18:00

It is also open today and all holiday days, in case anyone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally only shops in long-range train stations are opened on Sundays and holidays (I'm not German but I think it's a law). Your only (slim) hope is with the one in Alexanderplatz. If Rossman instead of DM is fine, too, you have good chances to find the one in Hauptbahnhof open.